OpenTelemetry span recordException with Quarkus / RabbitMQ
I have been working on a Quarkus proto about messaging and observability, using rabbitMQ and opentelemetry.
Everything works fine but now I am trying to get some error handling in the pipe.
So I have been doing this code :
    @Incoming("orientation-done")
    @Blocking
    public CompletionStage<Void> process(Message<byte[]> orientationResponse) throws InvalidProtocolBufferException {
        log.info("Received orientation response: {}", orientationResponse);
        OrientationUpdated message = OrientationUpdated.parseFrom(orientationResponse.getPayload());
        if (!message.getOrientationMessage().hasCer()) {
            log.info("MESSAGE NOT ACKED");
            Exception ex = new OrientationException("Orientation does not have a CER");
            Span.current()
                    .addEvent("Orientation failed!!!")
                    .setStatus(StatusCode.ERROR)
                    .recordException(ex);
            return orientationResponse.nack(ex, orientationResponse.getMetadata());
        }
        log.info("MESSAGE DELIVERED AND ACKNOWLEDGED with uuid {}", message.getOrientationMessage().getUuid());
        return orientationResponse.ack(orientationResponse.getMetadata());
    }

My problem is that the exception is not added to the existing span as I can see in the logs :
2024-10-14 16:54:23,434 INFO [ine.sof.asd.OrientationProcessor] (vert.x-worker-thread-1) Received orientation response: io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.rabbitmq.IncomingRabbitMQMessage@27748c0a
2024-10-14 16:54:23,435 INFO [ine.sof.asd.OrientationProcessor] (vert.x-worker-thread-1) MESSAGE NOT ACKED
2024-10-14 16:54:23,437 FINE [io.ope.sdk.tra.SdkSpan] (vert.x-worker-thread-1) Calling addEvent() on an ended Span.
2024-10-14 16:54:23,438 FINE [io.ope.sdk.tra.SdkSpan] (vert.x-worker-thread-1) Calling setStatus() on an ended Span.
2024-10-14 16:54:23,441 FINE [io.ope.sdk.tra.SdkSpan] (vert.x-worker-thread-1) Calling addEvent() on an ended Span.
I think the event add and recordException happens asynchronously and that it happens when the whole span has been terminated, so after the error handling treatment has been achieved.
Do I assume right ?
How can I correctly add a new exception event to my existing span ?

You ate trying to add things to a span that is already closed.
Not sure about the code before and if there is something you can change.
In any case, you can always create a new span:
    Span span = tracer.spanBuilder("orientation-response").startSpan();
    try(Scope scope = span.makeCurrent()) {
        if (!message.getOrientationMessage().hasCer()) {
            log.info("MESSAGE NOT ACKED");
            Exception ex = new OrientationException("Orientation does not have a CER");
            span.addEvent("Orientation failed!!!")
                    .recordException(ex);
            return orientationResponse.nack(ex, orientationResponse.getMetadata());
        }
        log.info("MESSAGE DELIVERED AND ACKNOWLEDGED with uuid {}", message.getOrientationMessage().getUuid());
        return orientationResponse.ack(orientationResponse.getMetadata());
        LOG.info("Message received");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        span.recordException(e);
    } finally {
        span.end();
    }

Some things that you need to consider:

If you record an exception, the status will already be an ERROR.
Always operate the span inside a scope. This way, you now where it will end and it will always end.
The tracer can be injected.


that does the trick!
Thanks.
